# UIApplication delegate must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, appdelegate, xcode9

I have a standard AppDelegate file in my Xcode project, I'm experimenting with Firebase and as soon as I imported it & added

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

I was flagged with purple warnings: [Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUhUa.png)

The whole AppDelegate looks as follows

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

These warnings never appeared whilst using Xcode 8, as a novice I am unsure on how to fix this, I have read that adding a DispatchQueue.main.async can fix it but I'm not sure where to add this.

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not with the code you posted. You need to post the code generating the errors in the image you posted.

Comment: The warning doesn't take me anywhere, I'm not exactly sure what part of my project is causing it to flag me, there is only one other ViewController file without Firebase implementation

Comment: @AlexKey please check here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/69 it's probably a bug of `firebase`

Comment: Click the triangle next to "Thread 3". That will show a stack trace. That stack trace will show you the code causing the problem.

Comment: @AndraMungaini Thanks for your reply, after checking it appeared that the version of Firebase I was using was bugged which was causing the warning, after updating the pods it seems to have resolved. Thanks!